# NoReverseMatch Django error when trying to view cart - using Python 3.6

Tags: django, python-3.x, session, django-templates

I'm getting the following error, and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

```
NoReverseMatch at /cart/
Reverse for 'add_to_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)  tried: ['cart\\/add\\/(?P<product_id>[^/]+)$']
```

I had no problems until I made some changes to my template. I also changed my product's pk values but I'm guessing that shouldn't affect anything? I also used `clearsessions` to in case that might have been the problem. I think that Django is saying it can't find a match for the url that I'm providing, but everything seems right to me. I made some changes to my code, and tried to revert it to a previous state, but I'm still getting the same error messages. I'll present my code, and if you could tell me where I'm likely making a mistake, that would be awesome.

Here is my product_detail.html template

```
{% extends "buylist/Header.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>{{product.name}}</p>
  <p>{{product.price}}</p>
    <form action="{% url 'add_to_cart' product.id %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="{{product.quantity}}">
      <button type="submit">add</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I use a form to link the url with the product url and add that to my cart
Here are my associated urls.py and Views.py

> urls.py

```
    path('cart/', views.get_cart, name='cart'),
path('cart/add/<product_id>', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
path('product/<product_id>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

> views.py

```
    def product_detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    return render(request, 'buylist/product_detail.html', {'product':product})

def add_to_cart(request, product_id):
    quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,id=product_id)
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart.add(product, product.price, quantity)
    return redirect('cart')


def get_cart(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'buylist/cart.html', {'cart':cart})
```

and here is the template for my cart

> cart.html

```
{% extends 'buylist/Header.html' %}

    {% block content %}

    <h1>Your Cart</h1>
        {% for a in cart %}
            <form action="{% url 'add_to_cart' a.product.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}

            <h4><a href= '{{a.product.get_absolute_url}}'>{{a.product.name}}</a><small>
              <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="{{product.quantity}}" value="{{a.quantity}}">

            <br><button type="submit">Update</button></small></h4>
            <p>Price :

            {{a.price}}</p>
            </form>
        {% endfor %}

        <b>Total items: {{cart|length}}</b><br>
        <b>Total Price: {{cart|length}}</b><br>

    {% endblock %}
```

If you could help me out, that would be awesome!

Comment: Try to print the route parameters -  `product.id` and `a.product.id` in your template so as to see whether these variables really contain what you expect. Note Django template language won't warn you that the variable or dict key don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure value of `product.id` and `a.product.id` is present when using `url` templatetag.

`url` template tag uses `reverse` function along with other arguments to create the url. (Code snippet below for reference)

```
    # Try to look up the URL. If it fails, raise NoReverseMatch unless the
    # {% url ... as var %} construct is used, in which case return nothing.
    url = ''
    try:
        url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
    except NoReverseMatch:
        if self.asvar is None:
            raise
```

As shown in the error

> Reverse for 'add_to_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found....

The argument tuple has empty string as first argument which does not match the provided pattern for `add_to_cart`.

Comment: After troubleshooting, I found that those values were not present because I made changes to my database without clearing my cookies, so it was trying to find the reverse for an id that didn't exist. I cleared the cookies on my computer and that fixed it. Maybe the best way to avoid this happening is to add a simple if statement checking if the item is in database and remove it from cart if not? Thanks again!